# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs AndroidManifest.xml:requires a placeholder substitution but no value for

Tags: android

Below is the unexpected error. How can I debug this?

> Merging Errors: Error: Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at AndroidManifest.xml:50:9-52:51 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided. app main manifest (this file), line 49 Error: Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml:54:9-56:70 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided. app main manifest (this file), line 53

Code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.muhammadtehmoor.my_fyp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my build.gradle (app level). I have imported most of the dependencies from the Firebase plugin in Android Studio.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
//    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.muhammadtehmoor.my_fyp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false


        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.9'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:animated-edit-text:2.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'
    //glidle
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Mahfa:DayNightSwitch:1.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //firebase ui
//    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'

}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my build.gradle (project :my_Fyp). I have imported most of the dependencies from the Firebase plugin in Android Studio.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
//}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        maven {url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven'}
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: below your manifest there are two tabs. 'Text' and 'Merged Manifiest'. Open the merged manifest and see

Answer (score 5):

The error message suggests that the OneSignal library is not configured correctly. Looking trough their [setup instructions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) it seems like you missed point 1.3. 
Add this to the app level build.gradle; inside the `android`/`defaultConfig` tag:

```
  manifestPlaceholders = [
      onesignal_app_id: 'PUT YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID HERE',
      // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
      onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
  ]
```

Comment: how to get the id of app

Comment: @tehmoor-hameed That's at the [top](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup#section-required-for-setup) you need an account and generate an api key.

Answer (score 1):

This might help...

Try going to your

> android/app/build.gradle

find defaultConfig and add the following

manifestPlaceholders = [
onesignal_app_id: 'ONE SIGNAL APP ID',
// Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
]

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.app.android"
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        onesignal_app_id: 'ONE SIGNAL APP ID HERE',
        // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
        onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
}
```

Your Onesignal Google project number is your Firebase Sender ID.